# MS Excel 2010 Max & Min

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

My database has 2 columns:
Column A contains date, Column B contains a value.
I use the `Max` & `Min` function to scan and correctly display the maximum or minimum value.
What I'd like to do is show the date that corresponds to the max or min value.
e.g.  if cell B1 contains the max value and cell A1 is the date, how to display the date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
=INDEX(A1:A20,MATCH(MAX(B1:B20),B1:B20,0))
```

[image]

Use a similar approach for *MIN()*.